# Does "await command.ExecuteReaderAsync()" wait for the query to finish before returning?

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await

I'm confused about the behavior of this command:

```
SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
```

I would ideally like to start the query running and as soon as SQL server starts returning results, start processing them. This is as opposed to waiting for all results to be returned by SQL Server. It appears like this could speed up my program by about 40% given when SQL Server Management Studio starts returning results for my query.

It appears that it should be possible and some places such as [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234.aspx) seem to indicate that it is.

I'm new to `async` programming, however, it seems to me like that command is calling the reader, spinning off a separate thread to do it, then waiting for the `ExecuteReader` to finish, which then returns a finished `SQLDataReader`.

Meaning that command is exactly equivalent to this without `async`:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
```

Or does the `SQLDataReader` returned from `ExecuteReader` naturally support streaming and only wait long enough for the stream to be available before returning? Does it work whether or not I call `ExecuteReader` vs `ExecuteReaderAsync`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no separate thread, it's just not blocking the current thread while the IO of talking to the DB occurs.  It will still wait for the DB to return before the code that follows it is executed.  `Async` is mostly about not blocking threads to either allow a UI thread to process UI events or to avoid overloading a Server with blocked threads that could be handling new incoming requests.  But it can also be used when waiting for other threads to finish CPU bound work as well.

Comment: Side note: post shows example of *executing* the query, but asks about *reading results* of the query (which is [NextResultASync]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223698(v=vs.110).aspx)). I'm not sure if this is caused by just mis-pasted sample or misunderstanding of how data is queried. Also usage of "return" is potentially confusing as `async` functions return immediately on first real `await` ...

Comment: How does the link you provided fail to answer your question about the semantics?  It demonstrates the use of the method, and specifically describes how it can be used to stream the results.  What about it don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however, it seems to me like that command is calling the reader, spinning off a separate thread to do it, then waiting for the `ExecuteReader` to finish, which then returns a finished `SQLDataReader`.

You [are wrong](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). What `async` methods are supposed to do is **start** an operation, **"pause"** the execution of current method, **freeing up** the current thread, and, **after** the operation becomes available, restore the state machine and call the rest of method.

Connecting to SQL server is an I/O operation, which should be run in asynchronous mode, because you don't really need a `.Net` thread for this operation. After connection is open, both synchronous and asynchronous reader will behave exactly the same - as normal `.Net` classes.

Comparing to synchronous version of this method you'll got one free thread at a time of connecting to the SQL server and a small overhead for a state machine.